# How would I change entity labels?

Tags: sonata-admin, symfony4

I use `Symfony4` and `Sonata admin`. When I use `ModelListType` it worked as shown on the screenshot below.

[image: Entity machine name is shown]

How would I change entity item machine name: `('App\Entity\Product:000000003aaca7040000000026c8b335')` to entity item  field 'name' value?

My code for this field is:

```
   #/project/src/Admin/ProductAdmin.php
   ...
   protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
   {
    $formMapper
        ->add('name')
        ->add('category', ModelListType::class);
    }
   ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solve this by adding *__toString()* method to entity:

```
    public function __toString(){
      return $this->getName();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just return the value directly by name instead of calling the getter method like,

```
public function __toString()
{
    return $this->name;
}
```